# What info is available about Independence Day aliens outside the movie?

Tags: independence-day

It strikes me as kind of odd that ID4 (Independence Day) never had any sequels, as by most accounts it was a great financial success and at least a moderate critical success.

Was there ever any other information about the aliens from ID4 released?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## MAJOR UPDATE - 2016 : including sequel material

- **Original film** tie-ins:

  - Original film had a tie-in ***novel/novelization "Independence Day"*** by Stephen Molstad. It did offer more information/details than the movie.
  - There was a prequel book about Dr. Okun (***Independence Day: Silent Zone***)
  - The same author who wrote a prequel had written a [midquel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midquel)/sequel novel ***Independence Day: War in the Desert***
  - All 3 of the above books were re-released as "The Complete Independence Day Omnibus" release in 2016, as a tie-in to the sequel film (see below)
  - There was also a computer game. It probably (like all games) had some extra details/backstory but I'm not aware of anything earth-shattering it added information-wise to the franchise
- **The sequel** (***[Independence Day: Resurgence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day:_Resurgence)*** - see SFF.SE tag [independence-day-2](/questions/tagged/independence-day-2)) was released in 2015.

  The film (and tie-in materials like novels) contained other information about the aliens. As of this update (November 2016) there are two tie-in novels (in addition to 2016 omnibus re-release of all 3 Stephen Molstad books tied into original film):

  - ***Independence Day: Crucible***, written by Greg Keyes - a prequel to the second film.
  - ***A novelization of "Independence Day: Resurgence"*** by Alex Irvine

    Interestingly, the novelization followed a likely earlier version of the script, with big differences *(as often happens, for example with Star Wars: <strike>The Force Hits the Snooze Button</strike> TFA)*, including a possibly-non-canon origin story of the Bad Alien Harvester species:

    > ... the sphere aliens are responsible for the creation of the Harvester aliens, who turned on them and wiped them out...
  - Additionally, Titan Comics issued a prequel comic book miniseries, ***Independence Day: Dark Fathom***

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(book_series)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(1996_film)#In_other_media

Comment: Personally, I want to see the sequel called "Vindication Day" and show the rest of the alien fleet showing up at Earth 30 years later... only to find that the humans have adapted the alien technology from the first movie and now use hybrid fighters & weapons. And not only are the humans prepared this time... they're mad.

Comment: @Omegacron - that's called "Ender's Game".

Comment: @Omegacron - ... or Harry Turteldove's Colonization :)

Comment: Worthy of an update. Since the sequel came out, there's been another canon prequel, a novelisation and loads of interviews, etc

Comment: @Valorum - what sequel? [Too bad they never made any ID4 sequels](http://xkcd.com/566/)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I was expecting the ID4 sequel to be dreadful, but in fairness they actually did a reasonable job. Not great, but reasonable.

Comment: @Valorum - I couldn't get past ~45 mins in so far, in 3 separate attempts to watch, to date :)

Comment: The sub-plot with the second alien species and the "queen alien" was wholly unnecessary as far as I was concerned. They should have stuck with "**10 years later, the same aliens come back and this time they're really pissed off and have brought even more ships**".

Comment: @Valorum - spoilers?

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I suppose, but it's not like there's much plot anyway. Just watch the fancy CGI and listen to the uplifting speech and you'll be happy.